# \lccode to be activate in latex command

Tags: active-characters

Why does `` \lccode`~=`, `` with an active `,` work only in an environment definition but not in a LaTeXcommand? We are using an active `,` to produce bullets:

[image]

Here is an MWE:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{xparse}

\makeatletter

\def\keybullet{\textbullet}

\newenvironment{keywords}{\bgroup\sloppy   \begingroup\lccode`~=`, \lowercase{\endgroup\def~}{${}\hbox{\ \keybullet\ }{}$}   \catcode`,=\active \noindent\textbf{Keywords}\hskip1em}{\egroup\par\addvspace{\baselineskip}}

\newcommand{\Keywords}[1]{\sloppy   \begingroup\lccode`~=`, \lowercase{\endgroup\def~}{${}\hbox{\ \keybullet\ }{}$}   \catcode`,=\active \noindent\textbf{Keywords}\hskip1em#1\par\addvspace{\baselineskip}}

\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{keywords} Harmonic balance, Multi-degrees-of-freedom systems, Fundamental harmonic, Higher harmonics, Energy method \end{keywords}

\Keywords{Harmonic balance, Multi-degrees-of-freedom systems, Fundamental harmonic, Higher harmonics, Energy method}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to absorb the argument *after* the setting of the category code, otherwise the commas would be tokenized when the category code has not yet been changed.

```
\documentclass{book}

\newcommand{\keybullet}{\unskip\space\textbullet\space\ignorespaces}
\newcommand{\activecommabullet}{%
  \begingroup\lccode`~=`,\lowercase{\endgroup\let~\keybullet}%
}

\newenvironment{keywords}
 {%
  \par\sloppy\activecommabullet\catcode`,=\active
  \noindent\textbf{Keywords}\quad
 }
 {\par\addvspace{\baselineskip}}

\newcommand{\Keywords}{%
  \par\sloppy
  \activecommabullet
  \catcode`,=\active
  \noindent\textbf{Keywords}\quad
  \Keywordsaux
}
\newcommand{\Keywordsaux}[1]{#1\par\addvspace{\baselineskip}}

\begin{document}

\begin{keywords}
Harmonic balance, Multi-degrees-of-freedom systems, Fundamental harmonic, 
Higher harmonics, Energy method
\end{keywords}

\Keywords{Harmonic balance, Multi-degrees-of-freedom systems, 
  Fundamental harmonic, Higher harmonics, Energy method}

\end{document}
```

[image]

A simpler implementation with `expl3`, that needs no category code change.

```
\documentclass{book}
%\usepackage{xparse} % not needed for LaTeX 2020-10-01 or later


\NewDocumentCommand{\keybullet}{}{ \textbullet\ }

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentEnvironment{keywords}{b}
 {
  \rajesh_keywords:n { #1 }
 }
 {}
\NewDocumentCommand{\Keywords}{m}
 {
  \rajesh_keywords:n { #1 }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \rajesh_keywords:n
 {
  \par\sloppy\noindent\textbf{Keywords}\quad
  \clist_set:Nn \l_tmpa_clist { #1 }
  \clist_use:Nn \l_tmpa_clist { \keybullet }
  \par\addvspace{\baselineskip}
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\begin{keywords}
Harmonic balance, Multi-degrees-of-freedom systems, Fundamental harmonic, 
Higher harmonics, Energy method
\end{keywords}

\Keywords{Harmonic balance, Multi-degrees-of-freedom systems, 
  Fundamental harmonic, Higher harmonics, Energy method}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Both are excellent definitions, this is I required. Thank you egreg.